# Couchdb replication --Unauthorized to Create or access database

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb

I am trying to replicate a database using .NET classes (httpWebRequest) instead of curl. Unfortunately, the cURL works, but the (assumably) same syntax in .NET fails with a 404 "Unauthorized to access or create database" error. Below is my code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("sourceURL");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;

        string json = "{ \"_id\":\"database_replicate" + ticks + "\", \"source\":\"sourceURL/database\", \"target\":\"database\", \"create_target\":true, \"user_ctx\": { \"roles\": [\"_admin\"] } }";

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(json);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Then it fails right here, on the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I am replicating to and from localhost. I've tried passing the credentials using request.Credentials, but that doesn't change the problem. Neither does passing the credentials explicitly in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that my username and password weren't being caught. Whether I tried passing them in as part of the url, or as a credential attribute, it wasn't picking them up. I had to create an authorize header like this

```
$authorization = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password")) 
$delRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "authType " + $authorization)
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

As your code is written, the json string will look like this:

```
{
    "_id":"database_replicate634805792932046092",
    "source":"sourceURL/database",
    "target":"database",
    "create_target":true,
    "user_ctx": {
        "roles": ["_admin"]
    }
}
```

When you use cURL, what are you sending?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As it turns out, it wasn't catching my authentication--that was the hang-up. So I explicitly created an Authorize header and it worked. In cURL I was sending the username and password in the url, but I had to do it explicitly in .NET.

Comment: I've been struggling for 3 days with a related problem.  Turns out the user_ctx parameter was all I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I was also stuck on the `user_ctx` parameter. For anyone curious about what it does and why you need it, check out this [subtle spot in the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/replication/replicator.html#delegations)